# ¿Como solucionar el error en el switch/case? Java

Tags: java

Se solicita desarrollar el algoritmo que permita analizar el comportamiento de las ventas de la Heladería “La dulzura”.

Para esto se solicita ingresar una muestra de 5 ventas durante un período de tiempo.

Se debe ingresar:

a. Tamaño del helado:

i. c (Vaso chico)

ii. m (Vaso mediano)

iii. g (Cucurucho)

b. Cantidad

c. Precio

Se debe calcular:

a. Importe total vendido

b. Importe promedio por venta

c. Orden de las presentaciones en función de las ventas (Que tamaño de helado se vende más, cual menos, y cual está en el medio)

Mi problema es que, cuando ingreso `vaso chico` o `vaso mediano`, me sale `Error` (el valor default del switch), pero cuando ingreso cucurucho no pasa ésto y no puedo encontrar el error.

```
int ventas = 6;
    String helados = " ";
    int cantidad1 = 0;
    int cantidad2 = 0;
    int cantidad3 = 0;
    int precio1 = 20;
    int precio2 = 30;
    int precio3 = 15;
    int total1 = 0;
    int total2 = 0;
    int total3 = 0;
    int totalVendido = 0;
    double promedioVenta = 0;
    int cantidad = 0;

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 1; i < ventas; i++) { //El contador empieza desde el 1 hasta menor al valor de ventas

        System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese tamaño de helado (vaso chico / vaso mediano / cucurucho) : ");
        helados = teclado.next();


        switch (helados) {

        case "vaso chico":

            System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese Cantidad : ");
            cantidad = teclado.nextInt();

            total1 = precio1 * cantidad;

            cantidad3++;

            System.out.println("Total : " + total1);


            break;

        case "vaso mediano":

            System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese Cantidad : ");
            cantidad = teclado.nextInt();

            total2 = precio2 * cantidad;

            cantidad2++;

            System.out.println("Total : " + total2);


            break;

        case "cucurucho":

            System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese Cantidad : ");
            cantidad = teclado.nextInt();

            total3 = precio3 * cantidad;

            cantidad3++;

            System.out.println("Total : " + total3);


            break;

        default:

            System.out.println("Error!");

            break;

        }

    }

    totalVendido = cantidad1 + cantidad2 + cantidad3;

    System.out.println("Importe total vendido : " + totalVendido);

    promedioVenta = totalVendido / 5;

    System.out.println("Importe promedio por venta : " + promedioVenta);

    if (cantidad1 > cantidad2 && cantidad2 > cantidad3) {

        System.out.println("1°.Vaso Chico . \n 2°.Vaso Mediano . \n 3°.Cucurucho .");
    }

    else if (cantidad2 > cantidad3 && cantidad3 > cantidad1) {

        System.out.println("1°.Vaso Mediano . \n 2°.Cucurucho . \n 3°.Vaso Chico .");

    }

    if (cantidad3 > cantidad1 && cantidad1 > cantidad2) {

        System.out.println("1°.Cucurucho . \n 2°.Vaso Chico . \n 3°.Vaso Mediano .");

    }
```

Comment: ¿QUé error sale? Como aprendizaje para la vida, procura reportar errores siempre incluyendo el mensaje o la traza completa. "Un error" puede ser cualquier cosa.

Comment: Cuando ingreso : vaso chico o vaso mediano me sale error , es decir , me sale directamente el default , en cambio cuando  ingreso cucurucho me deja ingresar la cantidad eso pasa!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambia en :

```
helados = teclado.next();
```

Por:

```
helados = teclado.nextLine();
```

Cuando usas `next` solo utiliza la primera palabra antes del espacio.

Answer (score 1):

Algunos consejos para determinar dónde está fallando el código (sin entrar en herramientas de debug):

**1. Simplifica el problema.**

Seguramente tienes alguna indicación de dónde está fallando el programa: extrae la parte que crees que falla y ve añadiendo complejidad hasta que algo falle. Por ejemplo:
tienes una lectura de un string por teclado, que se pasa a un *switch*, puedes poner esa parte en una clase de prueba y obviar la entrada de teclado probando con los strings que se pueden esperar:

```
package pruebas;

public class Zzz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("vaso chico");
        test("vaso mediano");
        test("cucurucho");
        test("xxx");
    }

    public static void test(String option) {
        switch (option) {

            case "vaso chico":
                System.out.println("Seleccionado vaso chico");
                break;

            case "vaso mediano":
                System.out.println("Seleccionado vaso mediano");
                break;

            case "cucurucho":
                System.out.println("cucurucho");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Error !" + option);
                System.out.println("---> " + option); // HACK: trace
        } // switch
    }

} // class
```

**2. Usa trazas.**

En el código anterior he añadido la línea:

```
System.out.println("---> " + option); // HACK: trace
```

En caso de que se entre en la condición *default* sabrás qué string se está evaluando. Si el string no es lo que esperabas, comprueba su origen.

**3. Combina trazados con finalizaciones.**

Puedes añadir trazas para determinar si el programa pasa por determinados puntos y finalizar la ejecución en diferentes puntos.

```
// code
// ...
System.out.println(" line 12" ); // HACK: trace
// code
// ...
System.out.println(" line 17" ); // HACK: trace
// code
// ...
System.out.println(" line 23" ); // HACK: trace
System.exit(0);
```

**4. Refactoriza para hacer el código más fácil de leer e interpretar.**

Usa métodos para separar las diferentes acciones. Además, si tienes partes repetidas puedes reestructurar para reducir el código fácilmente, por ejemplo, fíjate en que estas repitiendo lo siguiente en cada *case* del *switch*:

```
System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese Cantidad : ");
cantidad = teclado.nextInt();
```

Ok, ¿no quieres preguntar si no te introducen una opción válida? Por eso no se puede introducir esta parte antes del switch, pero si puedes usar un método para preguntar la cantidad:

```
cantidad = getQuantity(teclado, i);

//...

private static int getQuantity(Scanner scn, int n) {
    System.out.println(n + ".Ingrese Cantidad : ");

    return scn.nextInt();
}
```

**5. Usa nombres significativos para las variables.**

Esto igual no importa mucho mientras escribes tu código hoy, pero dentro de 2 semanas verás... Yo aún no se que hace la *i* en el *for*, por eso el método que te acabo de poner es tan clarificador.

**6. Usa bloques *try-catch* con excepciones genéricas.**

Cuando se lanzan excepciones tienes trazados automáticos que te ayudan a determinar que falla. Poner el "trozo" de código donde falla el programa dentro de esta estructura suele ayudar.

Para el método que devuelve la cantidad, que por cierto creo que va a fallar si no introduces un número:

```
private static int getQuantity(Scanner scn, int n) {
    try {
        System.out.println(n + ".Ingrese Cantidad : ");
        return scn.nextInt();

    } catch(Exception e) {}

    return 0; // default
}
```